# How to store the ID of the user who sent a slash command and compare with user who interacted with a button in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, quick.db

I'm using the following code to create a quick database to store the ID of the user who called a bot via a slash command. I then want to compare this ID with the ID of the person interacting with the bot. My aim is to prevent anyone but the user that called the bot being able to interact with it.

The following code works but it's temperamental in that it fails without a clear reason on occasion (i.e. it returns the error which states that the person interacting isn't the person who sent the slash command even if they are).

I'm new to discord.js and quick.db tables so I'm hoping someone more competent than me has a better way of achieving this.

```
const   { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js'),
        client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES ] });

client.db = require("quick.db");
    
var quiz = require("./quiz.json");

client.login(config.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    if ([null, undefined].includes(client.db.get(`quiz`))) client.db.set(`quiz`, {});
    if ([null, undefined].includes(client.db.get(`quiz.spawns`))) client.db.set(`quiz.spawns`, {});
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift();
    
    if (command == "unlock") {
        message.delete();
        const m = await message.channel.send(getMMenuPage());
        client.db.set(`quiz.spawns.m${m.id}`, message.author.id);
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (client.db.get(`quiz.spawns.m${interaction.message.id}`) != interaction.user.id) return interaction.reply(getMessagePermissionError(client.db.get(`quiz.spawns.m${interaction.message.id}`)));
        const q = quiz;
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post your EXACT error in the question so that we know exactly what you have in the console (post it as code like you're doing to your main file here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
const db = require("quick.db");
```

You should be using:

```
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();
```

Other than that I haven't see any problems.